# conda simultaneous environment use

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I am on the process of developing and application using an environment: `myenv`

I activate the environment and then execute the application using:

```
conda activate myenv
(myenv) > python app.py
```

At the same time I have a brach of the code that uses the same environment.

I would say that this simultaneous use of the environment is interrumping one to another.

On the second application I am doing debuging using pycharm.

Am I right? May that be for another reason?

**The Error: ** While trying to run one application and debug another using the same environment the first application performance decreases more than 50%

Comment: Hi! What is your problem here? What error message do you get? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I agree with darthbith, it's not clear at all what you're actually asking. I also doubt that a 50% reduction in performance has anything to do with conda environments. It's much more likely that the other branch is simply less performant (regardless of what conda env you run it in)